# <br/> tag is affecting all my other divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im a newbie and im trying to create a webstie just for practice, I realized that when I want to line break one of the divs (just to make stuf fancy) all my other divs gets linebreaked though, which I dont want. how do you fix this?

```
<ul class = "nav">
            <div class = "head_dividers"><li> <a href = "file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html"> Hello <span>  World </span> </a> </li> </div>
            <div class = "head_dividers"><li> <a href ="file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html"> stuff </a> </li></div>
            <div class = "head_dividers"><li> <a href ="file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html"> Help </a> </li> </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: SORRY! my br tag is supposed to be in here:  <div class = "head_dividers"><li> <a href = "file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html"> Hello <br/><span>  World </span> </a> </li> </div

Comment: This is invalid HTML! Check: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  The only allowed child of `<ul>` is `<li>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have the `<li>` tags inside of a `<div>` tag. You can swap them if you like, but generally, `<div>` is a divider, and the `<ul>`/`<li>` items setup their own spacing/breaks (on each new list item).

The `<br />` tag, on the other hand, is used inside of your text to create a break at a specific point.

I would recommend something a bit more simple like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="head_divider">...</li>
  <li class="head_divider">Text<br />Here</li>
  <li class="head_divider">...</li>
</ul>
```

and use CSS to add any necessary styles/spacing.

Comment: Ty for the reminder, but the <br> itself is still affecting my other <li>, here is the code:   <li> <a href = "file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html"> Hello <span> <br/> World</span> </a> </li>

Comment: @MatthewFrancis Can you please create a [Codepen](http://codepen.io) so that I can take a look and see what is happening?